# DKIM verification and canonicalization of leading double dots

Tags: email, hash, dkim, canonicalization

Just wondering how can I properly verify my DKIM signature? Especially using popular service like Gmail, Yahoo Mail or Hotmail (if it supports DKIM)?

*Also, when transfer email as quoted printable in SMTP, the leading dot is converted to two, would this be considered as one or two dots when calculate the body hash?* I get this one from the specification, in [RFC 4871], page 25, it stated, that the dot-stuffing should only be consider as one dot.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help?
http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/08/08/how-to-check-test-and-validate-spf-record-in-dns-is-correct-and-valid/

Comment: the txt record for DKIM is ok to verify, I am thinking of the DKIM signature itself, I seems to get some different ways of verification from open source libs. I am reading [RFC 4871] at the moment.